# Getting an error when i try to use mysql in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

i am trying to use mysql as a database for my rails application.

here is what my database.yml file looks like

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: blog_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

and this is the error i am getting when i try the rake db:create command

> hilarl@isa009:~/workspace/blog$ rake db:create rake aborted! Please
>   install the mysql2 adapter: `gem install activerecord-mysql2-adapter`
>   (mysql2 is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.)
>
> Tasks: TOP => db:create (See full trace by running task with --trace)

and when i try `gem install activerecord-mysql2-adapter` i get 'ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'activerecord-mysql2-adaptor' (>= 0) in any repository'

i am using ubuntu with ruby 1.9.3p194 and rails 3.2.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what the contents of your Gemfile ?
you should add :

```
gem 'mysql2'
```

in your gem file, after that from your directory apps in terminal you should execute **bundle install**

Comment: have put "gem mysql2" inaisw the gemfile and tried bundle install then i get 'Gem files will remain installed in /home/hilarl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mysql2-0.3.11 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/hilarl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/ext/mysql2/gem_make.out
An error occured while installing mysql2 (0.3.11), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.11'` succeeds before bundling.'

Comment: i have also tried gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.11' and tried bundle install after that but still keep getting that error

Comment: what's your OS ? If ubuntu for example you should install native libraries with sudo apt-get install libmysql-ruby libmysqlclient-dev its happen because mysql2 gem need native dependencies from your operating system.